# JS promise inside promise

Tags: javascript, geolocation, promise, async-await, es6-promise

The `getLocation()` function that should retrieve location in 3 attempts returns `undefined` instead. `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` returns the correct position, but the problem is in the promise handling.

The problem is apparently that I am calling a promise inside promise. I am not allowed to use the `await` keyword inside `geolocate()` already declared as `async`.

Original call:

```
var getLocationPromise = this.getLocation();
// Do something...
location = await getLocationPromise;
```

`getLocation()`:

```
  async getLocation() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var geolocate;
      for (let i=0; i<3; i++) {

        geolocate = this.geolocate();

        try {
            var location = geolocate;//CAN'T USE AWAIT INSIDE ASYNC...
            resolve(location);
        } catch(err) {
            continue;
        }
      } 
      reject("Max geolocation attempts");
    });
  }
```

`geolocate()`:

```
  async geolocate() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          resolve(position);
        },
        (err) => {
          reject(err);
        },
        {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: `await getLocation().then();` === `await getLocation();` - doesn't it?

Comment: It gives different results. I had problem with `await getLocation();` returning `undefined`, so I use `await getLocation().then();` that seems safer

Comment: not sure why you use `async` on `geolocate` and `getLocation` - as neither of those functions use `await`

Comment: `//CAN'T USE AWAIT INSIDE ASYNC` - no, that's not right, you can ONLY use `await` inside `async`

Comment: That's the problem, can't `await` in `async`

Comment: you keep saying that, but the fact is `await` can only be used inside a function declared `async` - are those first lines of code (labelled Original call:) inside a function declared async?

Comment: @JaromandaX is right, why are you saying that you can't use await inside async?

Answer (score 2):

As long as the following is in a function declared async

```
var getLocationPromise = this.getLocation();
// Do something...
location = await getLocationPromise;
```

it should be fine as is

looking at getLocation/geolocate, unless you need a separate geolocate method, they should be able to be combined and simplified to

```
getLocation() {
    var geolocate = () =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: 20000,
                maximumAge: 1000
            });
        );
    // this function will "retry" the supplied function (fn) cont times
    var limitedPromiseRetry = (fn, cont) => fn().catch(err => cont > 0 ? limitedPromiseRetry(fn, cont-1) : Promise.reject('Max number of geolocation attempts'));
    return limitedPromiseRetry(geolocate, 3);
}
```

Comment: Nice and compact solution, it avoids using the double promise. From your response I understand that putting promise inside promise is not a good idea and is not supported?

Comment: no, it is supported, it's just not required in this case

Answer (score 1):

### async and await

You can not use `await` inside functions *without* the `async` keyword. So the error occurs because the executor function is *not* `async`:

```
var getLocation = async function(){ // <-- this function has "async" keyword, but ...
    return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ){ // <-- ... this "executor" function has no "async" keyword.
        var value = await geolocate();               // <-- ERROR: await is only valid in async function.
        resolve( value );
    })
};
```

But you **should not** make the promise executor an `async` function.
See https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-async-promise-executor for more info.

```
new Promise( async function( resolve, reject ){ // <-- BAD ! Don't do it !
   ...
})
```

### without nested promise

But as `getLocation` is a promise already, you do not need the nested `new Promise( ... )` at all:

```
var getLocation = async function(){ // <-- "async" makes a function to be a promise
    var value = await geolocate();

    // "return value" inside async function is "the same" as
    // "resolve( value )" in a promise
    return value;
};
```

So, theoretically, you could solve your problem in the following way (although there are probably better ways of doing it. For 'rejecting' inside async function, see also [How to reject in async/await syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453683/how-to-reject-in-async-await-syntax)).

```
var getLocation = async function(){
    for( let i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
        try {
            console.log('try ...', i);
            var location = await geolocate(i);
            console.log('... success');
            return location;
        } catch(err) {
            console.log('... next try');
            continue;
        }
    }
    return Promise.reject('no success');
};

getLocation().then(function(result){
    console.log('then:', result);
}).catch(function(reason){
    console.log('error:', reason);
})
```

### nested Promises

Promises inside promises are ok.
Note that resolving promises with resolved promises behaves *"the same"* as resolving only one promise. You will not notice any difference in the `.then()` function, no matter if you resolve a value, or a resolved promise inside a promise, ... and so on.

```
var nestedPromises = new Promise( function( resolve1, reject1 ){
    resolve1( new Promise( function( resolve2, reject2 ){
        resolve2( new Promise( function( resolve3, reject3 ){
            resolve3('resolved value');
        }));
    }));
});

nestedPromises.then( function( value ){
    console.log('value:', value);   // <-- "value: resolved value"
})
```