# How to reject in async/await outside of catch statement?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

As outlined by [this SO post and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453683/how-to-reject-in-async-await-syntax), it is customary to throw an error from the catch statement that resides inside an async/await function like so:

```
} catch (error) {
    throw new Error(400);
}
```

As highlighted by that same post, you typically wouldn't return a rejected promise (see below) since it's a semantic mis-match with 'try-catch' statements.

```
} catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error(400));
}
```

**By that same logic, should I be returning rejected promises when returning errors outside of catch statements from my async/await function instead of throwing them?**

In other words is the following semantically inconsistent with the above logic?

```
async function promise () {
    throw new Error('Some error');
}
```

And, is this the preferred way of returning an error inside an async/await function since async/await functions implicitly return a promise?

```
async function promise () {
    return Promise.reject(new Error(400));
}
```

I'm aware both of the above snippets allow errors to be caught when consuming the promise.

Comment: IMO, you just throw the error. It doesn't matter whether you're throwing from within a catch block or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally use `throw` where you can, i.e. in `async function`s or `then` callbacks, because it is simpler and therefore easier to read. `return Promise.reject(…)` does work but is lengthy.