# Typescript simplification

Tags: typescript

We have a common code pattern in our typescript code base:

```
  public async publish(event: myEvent, myStr: string): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        await this.doCoolStuff(event, myStr);
        return resolve();
      } catch (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
    });
  }
```

Looking to simplify the code to not repeat most of that body, so that it looks something in the ballpark of:

```
  public async publish(event: myEvent, myStr: string): Promise<void> {
    return new HelperOfSomeSort() {
      this.doCoolStuff(event, myStr);
    }
  }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Whats the point of all that code? Just call and return `this.doCoolStuff(event, myStr);`.

Comment: How do you deal with exceptions if you don't have the try/catch?

Comment: You can catch the exceptions directly on the promise when you call it: `doCoolStuff(params).then(res => whatever()).catch(err => console.log(err))`

Comment: I found some good background info at the following SO question. Going to have to do some testing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453683/how-to-reject-in-async-await-syntax

Comment: This seems to be the go-to for the topic... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Answer (score 0):

I think the new Promise is useless since the `doCoolStuff` is will return a promise.
For the catch part then call the reject, the await will pass the erreur to the `publish` promise.

```
public async publish(event: myEvent, myStr: string): Promise<void> {
    return await this.doCoolStuff(event, myStr);
}
```