# Use external function in await and use a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I have my function `handleRes` who is exec in `await`.

But i want exec a function when the `await` is ended. Like with `.then` or `.catch`

How can i do something like this

**I import this function**

```
 const handleRes = res => {
    res
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log('done');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error');
      });
  };
```

**Read it in this file and exec something when it end**

```
await handleRes(res).then(() => setLoading(false));
```

Comment: Anything after `await` is like the `.then()`, and use a `try { } catch` around the `await` to simulate the `.catch()`.

Comment: How to [catch error with `async/await`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42453683/1218980)

Comment: @EmileBergeron - The problem is that `handleRes`, as written above, suppresses the error (and also provides no way for the caller to wait for fulfillment or rejection).

Comment: @crowder yeah I upvoted your answer, I was trying to find a duplicate and additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`handleRes` doesn't return the promise chain, so you can't wait on its work to finish from outside of it. The solution is to modify it so that it returns the chain:

```
const handleRes = res => {
  return res
//^^^^^^
    .then(({ data }) => {
      console.log('done');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('error');
    });
};
```

Then you can `await` it. In the normal case, that would like:

```
await handleRes(res);
setLoading(false);
```

...but your version using `then` also works.

In the normal case, you would also remove that error handler so that errors propagate along the chain and are handled by the functions calling `handleRes` (or the functions calling them, if they pass the chain along). With the function as shown above (with the `catch`), the caller has no way to know whether the operation succeeded or failed, because the `catch` converts the rejection into a fulfillment (with the value `undefined`).

Comment: Does returning res.then()... return a promise? Or should the whole res be wrapped in a new promise?

Comment: @mind - Yes, the methods on promise instances (`then`, `catch`, and `finally`) all create and return promises. That's why the `catch` call in the OP's original code works; if `then` didn't return a promise, there'd be nothing for `catch` to be called on.