# Async UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I'm using Promise.reject

I've got this warning: Unhandled promise rejection warning: version  is not released

how can I solve this warning ? I'm trying to use try and catch

Thanks for your help

```
 public async retrieveVersionFromJira(versionName: string): 
 Promise<ReleaseVersion> {
    const searchVersionsUri = config.jiraApiUri + 'versions';
    const jsonResp = await this.jiraClient.get(searchVersionsUri);
    const version: any = jsonResp.find(version => {
        if (version.name == versionName) {
            if (version.released == true) {
                try{
                  return Promise.reject("version " + versionName + " is not released");
               }
               catch{
                 return Promise.reject("error test")
               }
            }
        }
    });
    if (!version) {
        return Promise.reject("missing version " + versionName + " on jira");
    }
    return new ReleaseVersion(version.id, version.name, version.released);
}
```

Comment: What is `jsonResp`? The `find` code looks suspect.

Comment: JsonResp is a JSON response, it's all data from Jira and it's for this reason, I've got a JSON structur

Comment: All due respect, that tells me nothing. What is it? An array? An object? A string containing JSON?

Comment: Yes, it's an array

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer a bit about that.

Comment: If an async function throws an exception then the returned promise is rejected. You don't need to manually return a rejected promise. Just throw exceptions or let exceptions be thrown as you'd do in non async functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably two problems:

1. Not handling rejection. This problem isn't in `retrieveVersionFromJira`, it's in the code *using it*. That code needs to handle the fact that it may reject its promise. Apparently, the code using it is only handling success, not failure.

   One of the basic rules of promises (and thus, `async` functions, which return promises) is that you must either handle rejection (errors), or pass the promise on to a calling function that will handle rejection.

   If you're calling it from an `async` function, that function will automatically pass on rejection to *its* caller (which should either pass it on or handle it). If you're using a top-level `async` function, it needs to never reject (by using `try`/`catch` to catch all errors/rejections that occur within it), like this:

   ```
   // If this is the top level
   (async function() {
       try {
           const version = retrieveVersionFromJira("name");
           // ...use `version`...
       } catch {
           // Handle/report error
       }
   })();
   ```

   If you're calling it from a non-`async` function, that function also must either return the promise chain to its caller (which should either pass it on or handle rejection) or handler rejection, e.g.:

   ```
   // Pass it on
   function someFunction() {
       return retrieveVersionFromJira("name")
           .then(version => {
               // ...use the result...
           });
   }

   // Or handle rejection
   function someFunction() {
       retrieveVersionFromJira("name")
       .then(result => {
           // ...use the result...
       })
       .catch(error => {
           // Handle/report the error
       });
   }
   ```
2. The code in `retrieveVersionFromJira` calling `jsonResp.find` is incorrect. You've said that `jsonResp` is an array¹. `Array.prototype.find` expects the callback to return a truthy or falsy value indicating whether the current entry is the one you want to find. Your code attempts to return from `retrieveVersionFromJira` from *within* the callback, which it can't do. You also have `if (version.released == true)` followed by `return Promise.reject("version " + versionName + " is not released");`, which doesn't seem to make sense. You probably wanted:

   ```
   const version: any = jsonResp.find(version => version.name === versionName);
   if (version && !version.released) {
       return Promise.reject("version " + versionName + " is not released");
   }
   ```

   ...but see the note under the line below about `return Promise.reject(...)` not being the best way to handle rejecting the promise from an `async` function.

   ¹ ...in which case, it isn't JSON. JSON is a *textual* notation for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a **string**, you're not dealing with JSON.

---

Side note: Although it isn't the problem, the code in `retrieveVersionFromJira` shouldn't be using `Promise.reject`. See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453683/how-to-reject-in-async-await-syntax), the way to reject the promise from an `async` function is to use `throw`. Everywhere you've used `return Promise.reject(x);` you should be using `throw x;`. Also, since rejections are errors, it's usually best to use `Error` instance (e.g., `throw new Error("missing version " + versionName + " on jira");`.

Comment: @jeremy - No, you wouldn't do it like that. Again: The problem isn't in that function, it's in the code that **calls** that function.

Comment: @jeremy - Separately: The way SO works, questions are not meant to be moving targets, you don't edit the question to try to fold in answers. I've rolled back that edit.

Comment: Ok so it's not necessary to change this function, i'm trying