# How to handle authentication in TypeScript with Apollo Server GraphQL on Firestore Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, apollo-server

I've been following this article but attempting to do this in TypeScript instead of JavaScript:
https://medium.com/@piuccio/running-apollo-server-on-firebase-cloud-functions-265849e9f5b8

However I can't get the behaviour correct on when a `Authorization` header is not correctly supplied. In the code below I am throwing an `Error("No token")`. I also attempted to return a rejected `Promise` but that gave me a HTTP 500 error with `{}` (an empty JSON response).

```js
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import { Config } from 'apollo-server-cloud-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';


... resolvers, etc go here...


async function getUser(token: string): Promise<admin.auth.DecodedIdToken> {
    functions.logger.info('token', token);
    if (token === undefined || token === '') {
        throw new Error("No token");
    }
    const idToken = token.split('Bearer ')[1];
    const decodedIdToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
    return decodedIdToken;
}

export const config: Config = {
    schema: makeExecutableSchema({
        typeDefs,
        resolvers,
    }),

    // TODO: DISABLE THESE IN PRODUCTION!
    introspection: true,
    playground: true,

    context: ({req, context}): Promise<admin.auth.DecodedIdToken> => {
        // See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/security/authentication/
        functions.logger.info('req headers', req.headers);
        const token = req.headers.authorization || '';
        const user = getUser(token);
        // if (!user) throw new AuthenticationError('you must be logged in');
        return user;
    },
    formatError: formatError,
};
```

How can I return a valid `Promise` from `getUser()` for situations where the API supports anonymous access?

I'd prefer to use the Apollo Server `AuthenticationError` (as my authentication check) but I can't return `null` from `getUser()`.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestions over here: [How to reject in async/await syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453683/how-to-reject-in-async-await-syntax)

I can modify the type of the `Promise` to be `DecodedIdToken | null` and return `null` as a valid value. If I `reject` the `Promise` then an exception is thrown with the error string.

```js
async function getUser(token: string): Promise<DecodedIdToken | null> {
    functions.logger.info('token', token);
    if (token === undefined || token === '') {
        return null;
        // return Promise.reject("No token");
    }
    const idToken = token.split('Bearer ')[1];
    const decodedIdToken = admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
    return decodedIdToken;
}

export const config: Config = {
    schema: makeExecutableSchema({
        typeDefs,
        resolvers,
    }),

    // TODO: DISABLE THESE IN PRODUCTION!
    introspection: true,
    playground: true,

    context: async ({req, context}): Promise<DecodedIdToken | null> => {
        // See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/security/authentication/
        functions.logger.info('req headers', req.headers);
        const token = req.headers.authorization || '';
        try {
            const user = await getUser(token);
            return Promise.resolve(user);

        } catch (err) {
            return Promise.resolve(null); // "No token"
            // throw new AuthenticationError('you must be logged in');
        }
    },
    formatError: formatError,
};
```

So depending on whether you want the exception thrown or not, or if you want to use your own exception (such as `AuthenticationError` for FireStore) you can structure it the way you want.

Here are the different options:

```js
Promise.resolve(value)
Promise.resolve(null)
Promise.reject("Not valid")  -> throws exception Error("Not valid")
throw new AuthenticationError("Not authorized")
```

... or using the constructor syntax:

```js
return new Promise<DecodedIdToken | null>((resolve, reject) => {
  if (valid) {
    resolve(value);
  } else {
    reject("Not valid");
  }
});
```