# Why await statement is not working in new promise constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below code is giving me the error SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules.
I don't know what I am missing here.

```
function timeout(ms) {
return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function test(num) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        await timeout(1000);
        if (num == 11) {
            reject("error");
        }
        else {
            resolve("completed");
        }
    });
}
test(11).then((val) => { console.log(val) }).catch((err) => { console.log(err) });
```

Comment: relevant: [Is it an anti-pattern to use async/await inside of a new Promise() constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229)

Comment: The callback function inside a promise is not async so obviously you cannot use await in it. Granted it's an anti-pattern you could fix it by adding `async` keyword infront of the anonymous callback inside a promise ( `async (resolve, reject) => {}` )

Comment: `(resolve, reject)` to `async (resolve, reject)`

Comment: Thank you very much. It resolved. So, If I am correct it checks the one level above function is async or not.

Comment: @RohitKumar it checks *the current function*, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the function you're trying to use it in (the *promise executor* function you're passing the promise constructor) isn't an `async` function (and should never be). The `await` operator only exists in `async` functions. The job of the promise executor is to *start* the asynchronous process that the promise will report the completion of. If doing that involves using an existing promise (which would be your reason for using an `async` function, so you could `await` it), you don't use `new Promise` at all; you chain off the promise you already have. (More in the answers to [*Is it an anti-pattern to use async/await inside of a new Promise() constructor?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229). Spoiler: Yes, it is. :-D ) In your example, you'd just use the promise from `timeout`, like this:

```js
function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function test(num) {
    await timeout(1000);
    if (num == 11) {
        throw "error"; // (Best practice is to use `new Error` here)
    }
    return "completed";
}
test(11).then((val) => { console.log(val) }).catch((err) => { console.log(err) });
```

A couple of notes on that code:

- To reject the promise the `async` function implicitly creates, you either `throw` or return a promise that is/will be rejected. More in my answer here: [*How to reject in async/await syntax?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453683/how-to-reject-in-async-await-syntax). That's what I'm doing above with `throw "error";`.
- To fulfill the promise the `async` function implicitly creates, you `return` a value (`return "completed"` in the above). (More generally: to *resolve* the promise, you use `return`, which either fulfills it with a value or makes it follow another promise if you return one. My about that terminology in my blog post [*Let's talk about how to talk about promises*](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/).)